# MomentJS Convert Unix to Local Timezone and Capture From Now

Tags: momentjs

I have a unix timestamp that I am trying to convert to the local timezone and then to render the `.fromNow`. However I can't seem to find the best way to convert to the local timezone and the current formatting technique cannot be used with `.fromNow`. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong with the formatting and how I can get the local timezone of the user?

Unix Example:

`1541032289`

Attempt:

```
moment(1541032289).format('YYYY MM DD').fromNow();
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: moment(...).format(...).fromNow is not a function
```

**UPDATE:**

Code after replacing `.format()` with `.unix()`

**Code:**

```
store.zrevrange(zrangeSet, 0, -1, function(err, keys){
        var range = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++ ) {
            var keyObj = JSON.parse(keys[i]);
            keyObj.timestamp = moment().unix(keyObj.timestamp).fromNow();
            range.push(keyObj);
        }
        console.log(range);
    });
```

**New Error:**

```
            keyObj.timestamp = moment().unix(keyObj.timestamp).fromNow();
                                                                       ^

TypeError: moment(...).unix(...).fromNow is not a function
```

Comment: Which is your desired output? Please note that [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns a string, while `fromNow()` must be invoked on moment objects. I think you can simply remove `format('YYYY MM DD')` from your code and use `moment(1541032289).fromNow()` instead.

Comment: The desired output is to get the duration from the timestamp of the record to the current time. e.g. Posted 2 minutes ago, etc. I used `moment(unix).fromNow()`, but all of my values are coming up with `49 years ago`

Comment: you are right, I missed that your input is _in seconds_, I've added an answer to cover both issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code. First, [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns a string while you should invoke `fromNow()` on moment objects. So, you can simply remove `format('YYYY MM DD')`.

The second issue is that you have to use [`moment.unix(Number)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) instead of [`moment(Number)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

As the documentation states:

> To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch), use `moment.unix(Number)`.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment.unix(1541032289).fromNow() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but for some reason I'm getting an error despite following your setup `TypeError: moment(...).unix(...).fromNow is not a function`. I updated my question to reflect the how the function is being used within my actual code

Comment: @cphill please note that I've suggested to use [`moment.utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) to parse your input, do not confuse it with [`unix()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) getter.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying I should really input my value to an object as `utc` rather than `unix` and then run run this moment from the `utc` time? Your comment is the first time you mention that I should use `moment.utc`. Your answer says `moment.unix`. On a side note, I found the answer for my current setup: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3403#issuecomment-243121556

Comment: @cphill sorry, you are right, utc is not needed, cosider it a typo in my last comment (I should write unix, that is the function actually linked and used in my answer). The code in the answer is the good one.